# Apache Camel Cron Job Scheduling with quartz2

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, quartz

My aim is to schedule a job @ 15:00 hours every day from Mon-FRI. Below is my code:

```
CamelContext _ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
_ctx.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            public void configure() throws Exception {
from("ftp://Sid@localhost:21/equityFeedsProcessing/?password=sid#ftp&stepwise=false&useList=false&ignoreFileNotFoundOrPermissionError=true&fileName=data-sample.csv&"
                        + "scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=00+15+*+*+MON-FRI")
          .to("file:src/main/resources/?fileName=abc.csv");

            }

        });

        _ctx.start();
         Thread.sleep(30000);
        _ctx.stop();
```

Issues: 
1) I am getting a very weird exception: 
**Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: quartz2 of type: org.apache.camel.spi.ScheduledPollConsumerScheduler**
2) I understand that my program should be running when the job is scheduled. How should I ensure that. I mean do I need to run this program for the duration which I have set? and what value should I give for the sleep in *Thread.sleep()*?
3) Also how can I can make it to retry if it can't fetch the file?

**Please Note**: Exception the scheduler my program is running perfectly fine i.e. it's able to fetch the file from FTP server and download to my local location.

Please help in resolving the issue.

Comment: Do you have camel-quartz2 on the classpath

Comment: yes I do have. `<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
     <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
     <version>2.25.0</version>
 </dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

You could start the camel context every day at a certain moment. But why not run it always (so need for Thread.sleep)

For the retry mechanism see https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-handle-failures-when-consuming-for-example-from-a-ftp-server.html

The weird exception is probably due to some missing classpath issues

Comment: As mentioned in my post above I have camel-quartz2 on my classpath which is evident by the maven dependency  in my comments. Is there any version which has come up > 2.25.0 which is causing the issue? Really miffed about the exception. Not able to solve the exception. Please Help.

Comment: @Groote: Do we have a solution for this. As mentioned I have the camel-quartz2 on the classpath. What is causing the issue. Please help.

Comment: @Claus: How to resolve the exception. I have camel-quartz2 on the classpath. Please Help.